# Are my other partitions safe from harm from an alpha/beta release?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, 12.10, testing

I am quite intrested in testing the latest alpha-3 of Ubuntu, however, performance in VirtualBox is slow and somewhat buggy (I know! It's an Alpha) - guest additions wern't installing, bad mouse intergration, etc.

I would now like to test this release on my hard drive. But my main system (12.04) is also on this very same hard drive. Is this safe? Can the alpha touch my main partition? Are there any other risks?

Comment: Installing OS and resizing partitions is inherently dangerous, so yes, you *can* lose your data - but the chances of this are not very different from installing another copy of 12.04

Comment: I reserved some space in my hard drive on installation for windows fedora etc so I wouldnt have to do that. 400GB Ubuntu 100GB Free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed 12.10 to a new partition on your drive it should not touch your other data. The only partition that would be shared is if you have a swap partition which should not create issues.